# $count=true support in OneDrive API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

It looks like the OData $count parameter is not (yet?) supported in the Microsoft Graph API v1.0 for OneDrive.

Request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$count=true

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'Count' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e65aff74-1c6f-434b-8cd3-04e0c247fb71",
      "date": "2016-10-19T09:48:39"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

The `$count` parameter isn't supported with OneDrive. You can get a count of the children however by moving one level up:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/root/
```

This includes a `folder` property that contains the number of child items:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('id')/drive/root/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2012-08-03T08:12:58Z",
    "id": "{id}",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-10-18T14:19:21Z",
    "name": "root",
    "webUrl": "{webUrl}",
    "folder": {
        "childCount": 28
    },
    "root": {},
    "size": 0,
    "specialFolder": {
        "name": "documents"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. According to the OData spec, the $count system query should ba passed in the query string, see http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356.

Comment: Also the Microsoft Graph API describes this, see: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters#count